# Reactivar notificación al reiniciar dispositivo

Tags: java, android

Sé que necesito `BroadcastReceiver` y un `Service` pero imagino que antes necesito un *método* que reactive las notificaciones y luego llamarlo desde ahí. ¿Me equivoco?

Lo que hago es guardar el texto de la notificación en `Sqlite` y cuando se guarda lanzo la notificación, así:

```
        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                final String titulo = ed_titulo.getText().toString();
                final String notas = ed_nota.getText().toString();
                final String fecha = tv_fecha.getText().toString();
                //NOTIFICACIÓN
                noti();
                //
                Notas newNotas = new Notas(titulo, notas, fecha);
                mDatabase.addNotas(newNotas);
                ActualizaRecyclerView();
                finish();
                }
        });
    }

////

    private void noti() {

        uniqueID = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();

        notification.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        notification.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());
        notification.setContentTitle(ed_titulo.getText().toString());
        notification.setContentText(ed_nota.getText().toString());

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, otrointento.dos.Actividades.MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        notification.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        nm.notify(uniqueID, notification.build());
    }
```

Y esta es mi `Sqlite` donde se guardan los datos:

```
public class SqliteDatabase extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 5;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "DB_NOTAS";
    private static final String TABLE_NOTAS = "NOTAS";

    private static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
    private static final    String COLUMN_TITULO = "titulo";
    private static final String COLUMN_NOTAS = "notas";
    private static final String COLUMN_FECHA = "fecha";

    public SqliteDatabase(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String  CREATE_NOTAS_TABLE = "CREATE    TABLE " + TABLE_NOTAS + "(" + COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + COLUMN_TITULO + " TEXT," + COLUMN_NOTAS + " TEXT," + COLUMN_FECHA + " TEXT"  + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_NOTAS_TABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NOTAS);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public List<Notas> listNotas(){
        String sql = "select * from " + TABLE_NOTAS;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        List<Notas> storeNotas = new ArrayList<>();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, null);
        if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do{
                int id = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0));
                String titulo = cursor.getString(1);
                String notas = cursor.getString(2);
                String fecha = cursor.getString(3);
                storeNotas.add(new Notas(id, titulo, notas, fecha));
            }while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        cursor.close();
        return storeNotas;
    }

    public void addNotas(Notas notas){
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COLUMN_TITULO, notas.getTitulo());
        values.put(COLUMN_NOTAS, notas.getNotas());
        values.put(COLUMN_FECHA, notas.getFecha());
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.insert(TABLE_NOTAS, null, values);
    }

    public void updateNotas(Notas notas){
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COLUMN_TITULO, notas.getTitulo());
        values.put(COLUMN_NOTAS, notas.getNotas());
        values.put(COLUMN_FECHA, notas.getFecha());
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.update(TABLE_NOTAS, values, COLUMN_ID    + " = ?", new String[] { String.valueOf(notas.getId())});
    }

 /*   public Notas findNotas(){
        String query = "Select * FROM " + TABLE_NOTAS + " WHERE " + COLUMN_NOTAS + " = " + "notas";
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Notas mNotas = null;
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query,  null);
        if  (cursor.moveToFirst()){
            int id = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0));
            String titulo = cursor.getString(1);
            String notas = cursor.getString(2);
            String fecha = cursor.getString(3);
            mNotas = new Notas(id, titulo, notas, fecha);
        }
        cursor.close();
        return mNotas;
    }*/

    public void deleteNotas(int id){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(TABLE_NOTAS, COLUMN_ID    + " = ?", new String[] { String.valueOf(id)});
    }
}
```

¿Alguien puede guiarme? Gracias! :)

**EDITO3:**

`AndroidManifest`

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <receiver android:name=".Utilidades.AutoArranque">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

`AutoArranque`

```
public class AutoArranque extends BroadcastReceiver{

    public static SqliteDatabase mDatabase;
    NotificationCompat.Builder notification;

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")) {
            notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(AplicacionContext.getAppContext());
            notification.setAutoCancel(true);
            activaNotificacion();
        }
    }

    private void activaNotificacion() {
        //obtienes la lista con los datos almacenados
        List<Notas> notificacionLista = mDatabase.findNotas();
        //recorres la lista obtenida
        if (notificacionLista != null) //comprueba que no sea null
        {
            for (Notas datos : notificacionLista) {
                //reemplaza getId() y getNota() por los que correspondan
                noti(datos.getId(), datos.getNotas());
            }

        }
    }

            private void noti(int uniqueID, String nota) {

            uniqueID = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();

            notification.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
            Bitmap icon1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(AplicacionContext.getAppContext().getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
            notification.setLargeIcon(icon1);

            notification.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());
            notification.setContentTitle("Titulo");
            notification.setContentText(nota);
        //    notification.setOngoing((TxtPersistente.getText().toString().indexOf("true")>-1)?true:false);
            //
            Intent intent = new Intent(AplicacionContext.getAppContext(), paquete.nuevo.Actividades.MainActivity.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(AplicacionContext.getAppContext(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            notification.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

            NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) AplicacionContext.getAppContext().getSystemService(AplicacionContext.getAppContext().NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            nm.notify(uniqueID, notification.build());

        }
}
```

Comment: ¿Deseas que al reiniciar tu dispositivo se muestre la notificación? @UserNameYo

Comment: Que al reiniciar el dispositivo vuelvan a mostrarse las notificaciones @Jorgesys , es decir, cada vez que añado una nota a mi `RecyclerView` se crea una notificación, pues que esas notificaciones se muestren tras reiniciar el dispositivo.

Comment: Actualice la pregunta con lo que he intentado, como verás es parecido con algo que me ayudaste en el pasado, pero no consigo hacerlo funcionar. @Jorgesys

Comment: Sobre el error que has agregado, estas casteando `Cursor` cuando realmente te retorna el modelo de `Notas`: en tu método `activaNotificacion()` reemplaza `Cursor cursor = (Cursor) mDatabase.findNotas();` por `Notas notas = (Notas) mDatabase.findNotas();`, (despues tendras que modificar dicho método) o en su defecto, crea un método igual a `findNotas()` pero en vez de devolverte el modelo `Notas`, devuelva el `Cursor`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almacena todos los resultados de la DB en una lista para posteriormente retornarlos.

Método findNotas():

```
public List<Notas> findNotas() {
    List<Notas> lista_notas = new ArrayList<Notas>();
    String query = "Select * FROM " + TABLE_NOTAS + " WHERE " + COLUMN_NOTAS + " = " + "notas";
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Notas mNotas = null;
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        do {
            int id = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0));
            String titulo = cursor.getString(1);
            String notas = cursor.getString(2);
            String fecha = cursor.getString(3);
            mNotas = new Notas(id, titulo, notas, fecha);
            lista_notas.add(mNotas);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        db.close();
        cursor.close();
        return lista_notas;
    } else {
        db.close();
        cursor.close();
        return null;
    }

}
```

Ese método se encargara de buscar y retornar una lista con los resultados, que posteriormente puedes acceder de la siguiente forma:

Función activaNotificacion():

```
private void activaNotificacion(){
    //obtienes la lista con los datos almacenados
    List<Notas> notificacionLista = mDatabase.findNotas();
    //recorres la lista obtenida
    if(notificacionLista != null) //comprueba que no sea null
    {
       for (Notas datos : notificacionLista) {
           //reemplaza getId() y getNota() por los que correspondan
           noti(datos.getId(), datos.getNota());
       }
    }
}
```

En este último codigo, has de reemplazar getId() y getNota() por los que tienes en tu modelo `Notas` ya que al no saber su estructura no se como llames a las variables.

Ejecutar cuando el dispositivo se encienda:
Primero declara el permiso en el Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

Por igual, declaras el reciver:

```
<receiver android:name=".Utilidades.AutoArranque">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Por ultimo, una clase que extienda de `BroadcastReceiver`

```
public class AutoArranque extends BroadcastReceiver {

public static Notas mDatabase;
NotificationCompat.Builder notification;
Context context;

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")) {
        this.context = context;
        mDatabase = new Notas(context);
        notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
        notification.setAutoCancel(true);
        activaNotificacion();
    }
}

private void activaNotificacion() {
    //obtienes la lista con los datos almacenados
    List<Notas> notificacionLista = mDatabase.findNotas();
    //recorres la lista obtenida
    if (notificacionLista != null) //comprueba que no sea null
    {
        for (Notas datos : notificacionLista) {
            //reemplaza getId() y getNota() por los que correspondan
            noti(datos.getId(), datos.getNotas());
        }

    }
}

private void noti(int uniqueID, String nota) {

    uniqueID = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();

    notification.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    Bitmap icon1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    notification.setLargeIcon(icon1);

    notification.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());
    notification.setContentTitle("Titulo");
    notification.setContentText(nota);
    //    notification.setOngoing((TxtPersistente.getText().toString().indexOf("true")>-1)?true:false);
    //
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, paquete.nuevo.Actividades.MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    notification.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    nm.notify(uniqueID, notification.build());

}
}
```

Comment: Hola @Israel ! Gracias por tu respuesta, me ha funcionado muy bien :) pero siempre recupera la primera nota de la lista, las demás las ignora, a qué se puede deber esto? Es decir, crea la notificación perfectamente, pero solamente de la primera nota de la lista, las demás las ignora. Necesito que lo cree de todas las notas de la lista, he actualizado la pregunta añadiendo más información, gracias !!

Comment: Voy a probar el codigo por si he pasado algo por alto, actualizo mi respuesta lo mas rapido que pueda solventando cualquier error

Comment: He editado mi respuesta, no me habia fijado que el cursor lo movias unicamente una vez, he agregado un bucle while para que lo recorra por completo, ademas de eso he agregado un pequeño control de excepcion, si al recorrer el cursor, los datos no existen al usuario se le cerraria la aplicacion, para eso comprobamos que el cursor no sea null ni menor a cero, en caso de que sea menor o nulo, retornara null, y antes de recorrer la lista para notificar, se comprueba que no haya retornado null para igualmente evitar errores.

Comment: Gracias! Ahora lo hace con todas :D, lo único que queda es activar ese método desde un `Service` he estado probando pero no lo he conseguido hacer funcionar, me podrías ayudar? Muchas gracias @Israel !!

Comment: He agregado a la respuesta un esquema que deberias seguir, no necesitas un service si solo quieres ejecutarlo al encender el dispositivo,basta con el reciver. No me encuentro ahora ismo en mi ordenador por lo que no he podido colocar un codigo completo, pero espero pueda guiarte, cualquier duda no dudes en preguntar.

Comment: Sí, eso es lo que hice, pero no se ejecuta el método al reiniciar el móvil, he añadido a la pregunta para que veas como lo hago, yo creo que bien, pero algo debo hacer mal @Israel

Comment: He editado la respuesta nuevamente, cuando se obtiene el intent en el bootreciver, tienes que usar ese contexto en todo, ya que no se puede obtener el contexto de la aplicacion. Por otra parte tienes que iniciar el objeto `Notas mDatabase`, lo he agregado tambien en el onRecive `mDatabase = new Notas(context);`, en caso de que no le pases el contexto simplemente elimina `contexto`

Comment: Perfecto! Ya puedo realizar correctamente lo que necesitaba, muchas gracias @Israel !!! :)